# How to wrap restkit calls into a service class, and integrate into a controller?

Tags: objective-c, restkit, soa

I'm just getting into objective-c, and need some help with this service class I want to write.

I want to create a APIService class, that uses restkit and returns the responses.

It looks like restkit is based on blocks, so when the http call returns, parses the json and returns the resulting collection, I have to somehow make my APIService methods return the response.

I'm looking for help on the skeleton structure of this service, as I am new to objective-c and restkit (which uses blocks).

I'm looking at this example which I want to setup in my own APIService class:

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Examples/RKTwitter/Classes/RKTwitterViewController.m#L18

```
- (void)loadTimeline
{
    // Load the object model via RestKit
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/status/user_timeline/RestKit"
                         parameters:nil
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                              NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];
                              NSLog(@"Loaded statuses: %@", statuses);
                              _statuses = statuses;
                              if(self.isViewLoaded)
                                [_tableView reloadData];
                            }
                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                              UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                               message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                              delegate:nil
                                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
                              [alert show];
                              NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
                            }];
}
```

Can someone help me flesh out this skeleton structure, with a method call like the timeline about, here is what I have now:

```
@interface MyApiService : NSObject
{
  @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) RKObjectManager *rkObjectManager;
  - (id)initWithRKObjectManager:(RKObjectManager *)rkObjectManager;
  - (NSArray) loadTimeline:
}

@implementation MyApiService 
{
  - (id)initWithRKObjectManager:(RKObjectManager *)rkObjectManager
  {
     self = [super init];
     if(self) {
       self.rkObjectManager = rkObjectManager;
       // ...

     }
  }


  // how to define method for loadTimelines when the call returns using a block?
}
```

Then I'll use it like this:

```
// Initialize RestKit
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
MyAPiService *service = [[MyApiService alloc] initWithRKObjectManager: objectManager];

NSArray *statuses = [service loadTimeLine];
```

**But not sure if this is how I will call loadTimeLine since restkit again uses blocks??**

Answer (score 1):

RestKit also uses delegates. This is how i do:

Import `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>` in your .h file.

Implement the delegate `RKObjectLoaderDelegate`

Load objects from a service like this.

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"//status/user_timeline/RestKit" delegate:self];
```

Implement the delegate methods:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {
// Do whatever with objects here...
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error POSTing object : %@", error);
}
```

There are many useful delegate methods for `RKObjectLoaderDelegate`.

You can follow a nice RestKit tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial).